# Why would this function in Lua be called with one extra argument?

Tags: lua

In file `linalg.lua` I have this function declaration:

```
function dot(A,B)
   return sum(mult(A,B),2); -- sum along second dimension
end
```

And then in another file I have these calls:

```
require 'linalg'

-- First fundamental Coeffecients of the surface (E,F,G)
local E = dot(Xu,Xu,2)
local F = dot(Xu,Xv,2)
local G = dot(Xv,Xv,2)

local m = cross(Xu,Xv,2)
local p = sqrt( dot(m,m,2) )
local n = div(m,concath(p, p, p))

-- Second fundamental Coeffecients of the surface (L,M,N)
local L = dot(Xuu,n,2)
local M = dot(Xuv,n,2)
local N = dot(Xvv,n,2)
```

What I don't understand is:

> Why the `dot`function is called with three arguments (being 2 always the last of them) if the function is declared with two arguments? Is it some Lua idiom?

The code runs fine inside a system where it gives correct results, and now I have the task to translate it to Python/Numpy.

Comment: http://www.lua.org/pil/5.2.html

Comment: sorry, http://lua-users.org/wiki/FunctionsTutorial

Comment: @hjpotter92 from what I have read in your link, it's not clear if I can declare a function with two parameters and call it with 3 (by the way, I have never seen this in any language without an error message of some sort).

Comment: yes, you have seen it in several languages, but didn't recognize it directly. For eg. `print a, b, c, ...` in python. The extra arguments are ignored when you're calling a function. Less number of arguments won't raise an error either. They will be assigned a nil value.

Comment: @hjpotter92 just to clarify (sorry for the insistence), as I understand, you can make this only if you have `def function(args)` and then you unpack args, or check its length. That doesn't seem to be the case, `function dot (A,B)` states that you should call it with two arguments exactely. It's possible that former programmer thought the `2` parameter was needed when actually it's not, but then I wonder if that would generate an error, or the program would run properly, in the Lua case.

Comment: (I tried it in python and it gives: `dot() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54815/discussion-between-hjpotter92-and-heltonbiker).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from http://www.lua.org/pil/5.html

> Parameters work exactly as local variables, initialized with the actual arguments given in the function call. You can call a function with a number of arguments different from its number of parameters. Lua adjusts the number of arguments to the number of parameters, as it does in a multiple assignment: Extra arguments are thrown away; extra parameters get nil.

So simply extra arguments are ignored and missing arguments are nil. Yes. It is a part of how the language works and is perfectly fine to be used.

Answer (score 2):

I have ended up testing myself (don't usually use Lua, but have it installed) and it seems that it IGNORES extra arguments:

For example, in the snippet below, function is declared with two arguments, but called with three, and still works, since third argument is simply discarded, it seems:

```
function sum(a,b)
   return a + b;
end

local a = 1
local b = 2
local c = 100

local d = sum(a,b,c)

print(d)
> 3
```

Comment: It's not discarded. It's on the stack but inaccessible using built-in functionality. `echo "x=1 y=2 z=3 function f(a,b) end f(x,y,z,4)" | luac -l -l -v -`